# Apple watch wkinterfacetimer does not start

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am starting a watch development project.  It will basically be starting and stopping several timers on the watch.  The initial code works fine on the 42mm Simulator but not on the actual watch.  That is, tapping on the Start button begins the WKInterfaceTimer label running. Nothing happens on the physical watch. However, I know the timer is working because if I check Enabled in the InterfaceBuilder the timer starts incrementing as soon as the app launches on the watch. Here is the code for watch app extension.h and .m. The outlet is connected properly in IB.  Also, tapping on the Dispatch button enters the Dispatch IBAction and works correctly.  I have also tried powering off and powering on the watch. That does not help.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

interface controller.h

```
/
/
/
/
/
/ 
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceTimer *ElapsedTime;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *dispatchTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;
@end
/
/
/
interface controller.m
/
/
/
/
#import "InterfaceController.h"
@interface InterfaceController()
@end
@implementation InterfaceController
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    /
}
- (void)willActivate {
    /
    [super willActivate];
}
- (void)didDeactivate {
    /
    [super didDeactivate];
}
- (IBAction)Start {
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.ElapsedTime setDate:self.startDate];
    [self.ElapsedTime start];
}
- (IBAction)Stop {
    [self.ElapsedTime stop];
}
- (IBAction)Dispatch {
    NSDate *date =[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [self.dispatchTime setText:dateString];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure why the WKInterfaceTimer object doesn't work.  Instead, I used a standard NSTimer object and a standard NSDate object. The code works. Note: if you have another page-based storyboard scene that the first scene seques to, you have to add a custom WkInterfaceController object to the next scene and connect your outlets from the interface storyboard to it. Otherwise, the outlets won't connect because the file's owner isn't correct. Also, make sure that you add the custom WkInterfaceController to the watch kit extension target, not the iOS target.

```
    //
//  InterfaceController.h
//  EMSTimers WatchKit 1 Extension
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 12/18/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *ElapsedTime;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *dispatchTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *dateStarted;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *elaspsedTimer;
@end

    //
//  InterfaceController.m
//  EMSTimers WatchKit 1 Extension
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 12/18/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InterfaceController.h"


@interface InterfaceController()

@end


@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
}
- (IBAction)Start {
    NSDate *date =[NSDate date];
    self.dateStarted = date;
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1.0;
    self.elaspsedTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(calculateTimer:) userInfo:self.elaspsedTimer repeats:YES];
    [self.elaspsedTimer fire];
}
- (IBAction)Stop {
    [self.elaspsedTimer invalidate];
}
-(void)calculateTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{

    NSTimeInterval interval = [self.dateStarted timeIntervalSinceNow];
    interval = (-1 * interval);

    int time = round(interval);
    div_t h = div(time, 3600); //seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
    int hours = h.quot;         // hours, divided by 60 equals
    div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);   // minutes
    int minutes = m.quot;
    int seconds = m.rem;        // and remainder is seconds


    NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    [self.ElapsedTime setText:intervalString];
}
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
}

@end
```